# Add html to a page ( jsPDF )

Tags: javascript, jspdf

**In the example you can add text to each page:**

```
var doc = new jsPDF()
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!')
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.')
doc.addPage()
doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?')
```

I do not see in the examples that I can take the HMLT content of two DIVs on my screen by id and paint the contents of each DIV on a page

```
document.getElementById(DIV_ID_1)

document.getElementById(DIV_ID_2)
```

To finish I generate a pdf, in which on page 1 is the content of my **div 1** and on page two the content of my **div 2**

```
pdf.save('example.pdf');
```